# Удалить из файла все повторяющиеся слова в файле

Tags: c, файлы

> В текстовом файле содержатся слова. Удалить из файла все повторяющиеся слова.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i=0,count=0;
char a[1000];
char b[100][1000];
FILE *file=fopen("1.txt", "r");
FILE *file2=fopen("2.txt", "w");

//извлекаем из файла в массив
for(int i=0;!feof(file);i++){
fscanf(file,"%c",&a[i]);
  count++;
}

//записываем в файл по слову в каждую строку
for(int i=0;i<count-1;i++){
if(a[i]==*" "){
    fprintf(file2,"\n");
    }
    else{
  fprintf(file2,"%c",a[i]);
   }
}
  fclose(file2);

FILE *file3=fopen("2.txt", "r");
while(!feof(file3)){
fscanf(file3,"%s",b[i]);
printf("%d) %s ",i+1,b[i]);
i++;
}

fclose(file);
fclose(file3);

FILE *del_file = fopen("1.txt","w+");
for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
    printf("'%s' and '%s'\n",b[j],b[j+1]);
    if(b[j] == b[j+1]){                           //эти строки не хотят сравниваться
    printf("true %s ",b[j]);
    }


fprintf(del_file,"%s ",b[j]);
}
fclose(del_file);
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Знаю, что делаю по-идиотски, но по-другому не умею, алгоритм таков: посимвольно считываем из файла данные в массив, из массива записываем в другой файл слова, по слову в каждую строку, чтобы потом их считать в строки, затем считываем в массив строк, проблема в том, что строки не сравниваются между собой, условие не проходит (в коде помечено), что это может быть и как это исправить?

Comment: Потмоу что это не сравнение строк, а сравнение указателей.

Comment: @alexoander, я не стал оформлять, потому что это лишь проблема, а автор просит еще как её исправить.

Comment: Вы хотите только смежные (подряд идущие) повторы удалить? Или во всём файле дубликаты искать? Должен ли результат сохранять порядок слов в исходном файле? Что является словом? К примеру, сколько разных слов в строке: "слово Слово слово."? (точка в конце) Если пробелом разделены, то могут ли не-ascii пробелы встречаться. Приведите явный пример ввода/вывода.

Comment: @ВадимМороз если думаете что нашли решение, опубликуйте его как свой ответ, чтобы получить комментарии о решении и помочь другим людям с той же проблемой. [Это явно приветствуется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Какая кодировка текста в файле? Что такое "повторяющиеся слова"? Учитывается ли морфемное преобразование (файл - файла и т.п)? Если учитывается, то какое максимальное расстояние Левенштейна допускается? Что делать с первым словом из списка? Оставлять? Задание для креативщика!

Comment: Обычный текстовый файл, которые повторяются, те удалить, например, в файле "hello word word", а на выходе должно быть "hello"